# What can be used instead of ast module?

Tags: python, json, abstract-syntax-tree, evaluate, python-2.4

In my project I evaluate a json data to extract information. The code is as follows :

```
conn = httplib.HTTPConnection(host)
conn.request("GET", "/done_json.php")
r = conn.getresponse()
data = r.read()
tmp = ast.literal_eval(data)
list = []
for a in tmp.keys():
    list.append(tmp[a])
```

How can I change this to be Python 2.4 compatible ?

---

Sample of my json :

`{'key_64': {'size3': 'CNDCRNCDF3FY09XL7UUBCBCPTYE4H7YBG1I5MILNBW172BMHVI.png', 'id': 'CNDCRNCDF3FY09XL7UUBCBCPTYE4H7YBG1I5MILNBW172BMHVI', 'size2': '', 'size1': 'http://dev.geco.com/site/2/CNDCRNCDF3FY09XL7UUBCBCPTYE4H7YBG1I5MILNBW172BMHVI.png'}, 'key_65': {'size3': 'CNDCRNEHLW2XFFCC90PDE77EEJHJF6RC3R8PEVUACB0C34H330.png', 'id': 'CNDCRNEHLW2XFFCC90PDE77EEJHJF6RC3R8PEVUACB0C34H330' (...)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't use `ast.literal_eval`, it's the wrong thing for the job anyway. Use `simplejson.load(r)` (or the standard json module instead of simplejson in newer versions).

ast.literal_eval is designed to evaluate Python literals. JSON is mostly the same, but not entirely (true/false/null instead of True/False/None).

Comment: problem is that the returned json is a string. So running json.load(data) gives : `AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'read'`.

Comment: You use `json.load(r)`, with the r (response) object, which does have a read method. Or you can do `json.loads(data)` (note the s) if you really need to get the string separately.

Comment: simplejson.loads(data) gives this in contrary : `ValueError: Expecting property name: line 1 column 2 (char 2)`

Comment: so I should use some regex here ?

Comment: @DevAno1: "so I should use some regex here ?"  No.  You should get proper JSON that meets the JSON spec.  Failing that, you can try to use `replace()` to replace the `'` with `"`.

Comment: I'll agree with S.Lott: If possible, get the server to send valid JSON in the first place. There are several libraries for PHP, if you need them.